# iterate through html table rows with jquery to get div id inside <td> cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to iterate through each cell in each row in a table id="myTable" and get the ids of the cells' child divs.

So far I have something like:

```
$("td.theCell").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //this would give me the td id but I want its child div's id
});
```

my html is like:

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>foo</tr>
  <tr>bar</tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td class='theCell'>
      <div id='myDiv'>foo</div>
    </td>
  <tr>foo</tr>
  <tr>bar</tr>
</table>
```

Does anybody know a good way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("td.theCell div").each(function() { var id = $(this).attr('id'); //this would give me the td id but I want its child div's id });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("td.theCell").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('div').attr('id'); 
});
```

You need to get the **Id** of the div and not the td.thecell element right. 
So you need to use `.find()` to select the dive inside it..

Comment: what if instead of <td class='theCell'> I have <td class='theCell foo'>?  Does it work to use $("td.theCell foo").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('div').attr('id'); 
});

Comment: Then your selector should be  $("td.theCell.foo")  .. Remaining will be teh same

Answer (score 2):

Save all div ids in an array. using `.each` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWdZd/)

```
var dividlist = [];
$("td.theCell div").each(function() {
     dividlist.push(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also select the child divs directly without using find:

```
$("td.theCell div").each(function() {    
      var id = this.id
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the descendant div :

```
$("td.theCell").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('div').attr('id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a small change in the selector

```
$("#myTable tr > td.theCell > div").each(function() {//you can remove the '>' if you don't just want the direct children only 
  var k = $(this).attr('id'); 
  console.log(k);
});​
```